# How do I update Universal Provider connection string at runtime?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, universal-provider

We are using a membership provider based on universal provider and I want to change the connection string that it uses at runtime.

The following question http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/260d8536-c39f-41ec-b181-4d452cf054b3/ shows how to change SQL membership provider at runtime.

However if I do it with System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider then it doesn't work as it doesn't seem to have have _sqlConnectionString field to set.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the code from the following blog post

http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/asp-net-universal-providers-and-the-windows-azure-service-configuration/

Basically I inherited defaultmembershipprovider override its Initialize method accessed its connectionstringname and then used the ConfigurationManager http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx to update the web.config